# Why is insert performance into a large SQLite database so slow on MacOS?

Tags: python, database, macos, sqlite, file

I have a 15 GB sqlite database on an external SSD. It has 3200 tables containing 100k rows each.

I need to load 20 more tables into this DB from CSV files, again 100k rows each. There are some string and numeric columns. No indices or keys in any of the existing or to be added tables.

I am using a python script with pd.read_csv and df.to_sql to load the data.

It is taking 60 seconds per table on macOS and 1 second per table on Windows.
I am using the same database file and the same script on the same SSD in both the cases.

I am unable to understand why it is taking so long on mac.
When I try to load the data into a new sqlite db instead of the existing one, it takes the same 1 second per table as expected. But why is this same database file giving such drastically different insertion times on both systems is beyond me.

I have tried isolating the problem by using a new DB instead of existing DB (1 second per table on both systems), renaming DB (no change in the discrepancy), moving the DB's location (no change), copying the DB from SSD to disk (no change) and using sqlalchemy backend instead of sqlite (again, no change).

I am completely clueless about why this is happening and how to diagnose this issue further.

Comment: different systems don't have to work the same. Maybe all problem is system, not Python, not sqlite,

Comment: @furas the same mac gave 1 sec per table on the same database few weeks ago. Maybe I'll try with a different python environment, and via some other language. Will help isolate if the problem is mac or python.

Comment: Update - I tried using the sqlite shell (csv mode, import command) and it's taking 1 second. I tried using pandas on a virtual env, same 60 seconds. And to my surprise, on changing the table name from '01122023' to 't01122023' (or anything that does not start with an integer, pandas is also taking 1 second. So something's wrong with pandas. Will create a Github issue.

Comment: `sqlite` is absolutely the wrong choice for a 15GB dataset.  Seriously.  `sqlite` was designed to be lightweight and simple.  You need a real database, like MySQL or Postgres, and honestly, they're no harder to use than sqlite.

Comment: I hear that sqlite is significantly faster than traditional databases for reading. My use-case is very read-intensive (strategy backtesting on financial data) and writes are rare, no more than once a month usually (to update the database). That is the reason I went with sqlite, plus the portability is also very nice to have.